# How to disable classes popup while addind CSS in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How to disable this popup while adding custom CSS? I have to click plus sign multiple times to add the class to inspector.

I trid to find the solution but not sure what it is. Any clue or help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHVSS.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.